# convert an array of objects into a list in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, arraylist, vuejs2

I am trying to convert

```
[
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

into

```
[1, 2]
```

I created a computed property and a watcher:

```
<template>

  <div v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
    <approvers
      v-model="users[index].id"
      :users="users"
      :index="index"
      :ref="`option-${index}`"
    />

    {{ users }}

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    users: null,
    rule: {
      users: null
  },
  computed: {
    approvers() {
      return this.users.map(({ id }) => id);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    approvers() {
      this.users = this.approvers;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

but I still get an array instead of a list.
How to correctly use computed property and watcher in this case?

Comment: Looks like you just have to remove the watcher, overriding users is not what you want to do

Comment: you must remove the watcher and use `approvers` in your v-for loop.  `v-for="(user, index) in approvers"`.  It will work then